# How to make mutilevel menues in wp custom theme?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

> I have integrated html page in wp ,but problem arises when I tried
> to display  wp menus. I have also created multilevel menus in wp-admin.    I have used below method    to display menus .

wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) );

> what should i do ,to display multilevel menues in custom pages with their style

Comment: Improve formatting, correct spelling

Comment: Yoy can write your own walker class and use it to display the menu

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-level-navigation-plugin/screenshots/

Comment: witout plugin is it not possible ?.Because the html page,which i have integrated .has very nice static menues,Iwant to make it dynamic .As wp does